# Providing data frame with columns containing arrays to an auto encoder for training

Tags: pandas, keras, deep-learning, training-data, autoencoder

I am trying to pass a data frame with arrays in their columns as training data to an Autoencoder and then use the encoder layer to extract features from it but I am having troubles in getting the right data format to do it in.

```
dict_lists = {"col1":[[0.1, 0.2],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],...],
           "col2":[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],...],
           "col3":[[-0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.9, 0.3], [0.1, 1.2, -1.0],...]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_lists)

def generate_datasets_for_training(data, window_size):
    _l = len(data)
    Xs = []
    Ys = []
    for i in range(0, (_l - window_size)):
        # because this is an autoencoder - our Ys are the same as our Xs. No need to pull the next sequence of values
        Xs.append(data[i:i+window_size])
        Ys.append(data[i:i+window_size])
    
    tr_x, ts_x, tr_y, ts_y = [np.array(x) for x in train_test_split(Xs, Ys)]
    assert tr_x.shape[2] == ts_x.shape[2] == (data.shape[1] if (type(data) == np.ndarray) else len(data))
    return  (tr_x.shape[2], tr_x, tr_y, ts_x, ts_y)

feats, X, Y, XX, YY = generate_datasets_for_training(X, 8)

epochs = 100
batch_size = 16
window_length = 8

early_stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-2, patience=5, verbose=0, mode='auto',
    baseline=None, restore_best_weights=True)

encoder_decoder_model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.LSTM(256, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', batch_input_shape=(None, window_length, feats), return_sequences=True, name='encoder_1'),
        layers.LSTM(128, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', return_sequences=True, name='encoder_2'),
        layers.LSTM(64, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', return_sequences=True, name='encoder_3'),
        layers.LSTM(32, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', return_sequences=True, name='encoder_4'),
        layers.LSTM(16, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', return_sequences=False, name='encoder_5'),
        layers.RepeatVector(window_length, name='encoder_decoder_bridge'),
        layers.LSTM(16, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', return_sequences=True, name='decoder_1'),
        layers.LSTM(32, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', return_sequences=True, name='decoder_2'),
        layers.LSTM(64, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', return_sequences=True, name='decoder_3'),
        layers.LSTM(128, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', return_sequences=True, name='decoder_4'),
        layers.LSTM(256, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', return_sequences=True, name='decoder_5'),
        layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(feats))
    ]
)

encoder_decoder_model.summary()
encoder_decoder_model.compile(loss="mse",optimizer='adam')
encoder_decoder_model.build()
encoder_decoder_model.save('../models/autoencoder_model.keras')
history = encoder_decoder_model.fit(x=X, y=Y, validation_data=(XX, YY), epochs=100, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, callbacks=[early_stop])
```

My main issue is how exactly do I transform my data so that each array from each column is one sequence for the AutoEncoder. The sequences are NumPy-arrays and can have varying lengths, so I am aware that I have to pad them, but assuming they're padded and of the same length.

The end goal is to perform clustering on these sequences after extracting to see how many different types of sequence patterns are generated for each column.